# Qt Creator setting moc parameters

Tags: c++, qt4, qt-creator, moc

I'm trying to move my project from the VS2005 build system to Qt Creator.

We've set up visual studio to use moc for certain headers and output a .moc file with the same file name.

> eg:
> MyClass.h
>
> MyClass.moc

When QtCreator runs qmake and moc is run, it generates a cpp file with the file name prepended with moc_

> eg:
> MyClass.h
>
> moc_MyClass.cpp

I've found options for changing **where** moc outputs its files, but now how to  change the actual output filename. In our visual studio files we have basically

```
-o $(InputName).moc
```

Is there an equivalent way to do this in Qt Creator? I'm guessing it's something I put in my .pro file.

EDIT:

I've made some progress on my issue.

I found some documentation on how to have custom compilers and targets [here](https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-environment-reference.html) and [here](http://www.qtcentre.org/wiki/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake).

I've set up my 'new moc' tool to output moc files in the same directory as the header and name them as .moc files.

```
new_moc.output = ${QMAKE_FILE_BASE}.moc
new_moc.commands = moc ${QMAKE_FILE_NAME} -o
${QMAKE_FILE_IN_PATH}/${QMAKE_FILE_OUT}
new_moc.input = NEW_HEADERS

new_moc_echo.commands = @echo Moccing $$new_moc.target

QMAKE_EXTRA_COMPILERS += new_moc
QMAKE_EXTRA_TARGETS += new_moc_echo
```

It builds the moc file in the right place, however, I now get a linker error for my project.

```
MyFile.moc : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0xA02
```

I'm guessing something's missing from my moc build tool.

Comment: Why is it important/desirable to be able to choose a different file name for your moc files?  (i.e. what's wrong with the names that qmake chooses?)